# Core Data passing objectID to another thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, core-data

I've tried Googling and searching SO, thinking it would be quite easy to find but I'm surprised there were little to no examples of my problem in Swift.

I have several threads and from what I've read, it's best to have a separate managed object context for each thread. If I want to access an object from another context, I should pass around the `objectID`.

My question is, how should I pass the objectID to the context in a new thread?

Below is how the construction of my situation is:

```
func doSomething(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let person = Persons(context: context) // NSManagedObject

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) {
        let background = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).cdh.backgroundContext!

        Birthdays(context: background, person) // NSManagedObject
        saveContext(background)
    }
}
```

Birthdays has a one to one relationship with Persons. If I execute this code it will give me an error saying:

```
Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'person1' between objects in different contexts
```

Obviously because they are in separated contexts. So I tried to get the objectID of `person1` by `let personsObjectID = person1.objectID`, but I don't know how I should be using it to pass it to the other thread. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the only thing I needed to do was to add:

```
let person = background.objectWithID(orders.objectID as! Persons
```

If I've understood it correctly, `objectWithID` fetches the object from the store and puts it in the context, returning the managed object. It would be nice if someone could verify this if it's true.

```
func doSomething(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let person = Persons(context: context) // NSManagedObject

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) {
        let background = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).cdh.backgroundContext!

        let person = background.objectWithID(orders.objectID as! Persons

        Birthdays(context: background, person) // NSManagedObject
        saveContext(background)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hendrik, you are correct, you should use objectWithID to instantiate the NSManagedObject on the required context.